# asp.net - data type error of reading jwt token for login function

Tags: sql, asp.net, jwt

I successfully implemented function for registration including hashing password, but when I test login API, the console log throws this error:

"InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'."

"InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred while reading a database value for property 'User.PasswordHash'. The expected type was 'System.Byte[]' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'."

In my vs code there is no red underline, so I did not know where I was wrong. So what is the root of the problem?

Here is my code:

AuthController.cs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class AuthController : Controller
  {
    private readonly IAuthRepository repo;
    public AuthController(IAuthRepository repo)
    {
      this.repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]UserForLogin userForLogin)
    {
      var userFromRepo = await this.repo.Login(userForLogin.Email.ToLower(), userForLogin.Password);

      if (userFromRepo == null)
        return Unauthorized();

      // generate token
      var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
      var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("super secret key");
      var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
      {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.Id.ToString()),
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Email)
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
      };
      var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
      var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

      return Ok(new {tokenString});
    }
  }
```

user.cs:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

sql script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user]
(
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [email] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  [password_hash] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
  [password_salt] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
  [first_name] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
  [last_name] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
  [phone_number] [nvarchar](32) NULL
)
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `class User` you declared `password_hash`as `byte[]`, but in the db it's a `nvarchar`. Usually for `nvarchar` you need a `string` variable. When you use `byte[]` in your class, use `varbinary(255)` in the db.
Same problem of course with `password_salt`.

The exception comes most probably from this call, somewhere inside where the data is fetched from the db and written to the `User`object:

```
var userFromRepo = await this.repo.Login(userForLogin.Email.ToLower(), userForLogin.Password);
```

And you said there was no red underline in VS. This it's not a syntax error which could be recognized by the IDE, but a typical runtime error.
Set a breakpoint on this line and then step into the function by pressing F11. Then you should find the place where it actually happens.

Please also use [SQL-Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) as a good reference to choose the right datatypes.